# How to get quoted string in LESS

Tags: css, less

Think below rule in **LESS**:

```
p{ content: escape('a=1'); }
```

Compiled into css:

```
p { content: a%3D1; }
```

But I want the **result to have quoted** in CSS, like below:

```
p { content: "a%3D1"; }
```

How to achieve that?

I've tried below:

```
p{ content: %("%s", escape('a=1')); }
```

It's work but it's long and hard to write, any other solution about this?

Answer (score 0):

To write a simple and clear code you can create mixin that will take a raw string and will set a `content` to an element.

Mixin:

```
.escape(@string) {
  content: %("%s", escape(~"@{string}"));
}
```

Usage:

```
p { 
  .escape('a=1'); 
}
```

Output:

```
p {
  content: "a%3D1";
}
```